# Receiving Bluetooth Low Energy Data Via Android App

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

The project I am currently working on involves a weight scale that has built-in BLE and my smartphone. The scale connects to the smartphone via BLE to send the current weight data to its app (I assume this is prioritized.) Although I can't figure out how to get the correct UUID to communicate with the scale in my own Android App as it doesn't seem to be using the standard GATT Services. The devices seem to use 0x2901, 0x2902...0x290X

Scale model: HNY200 (Color Black)
Link to scale: https://www.healthometernuyu.com/nuyu-products/scales/wireless-scale/HNY200KD.html

After using a BLE scanner on my phone I was able to determine the BLE Name for the device (Much like the SSID in a network) and the MAC Address. However, it also shows a long list of CUSTOM SERVICE and CUSTOM CHARACTERISTIC options each with Descriptors and their properties such as read and write. I would assume the data im searching for (The weight value) would come packaged in a CUSTOM CHARACTERISTIC with the properties including READ. After analyzing each individual one the value is either the exact same hexadecimal number each time or has no value at all. The ones with no value instead have "OTA_STATUS", "OTA_CMD", or "OTA_DATA" but does not reveal anything besides that.

BLE Scan of the device looking at the most interesting characteristics (but not all):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoS75.jpg

I currently dont have any code for the android app as I am just following along with the Android Developers Tutorial. However, in previous research, It seems as though I will need the correct UUID's as I might have to reverse engineer the protocol the scale is using to send prioritized data to its app. Some BLE scanners work to find the scale and some do not.

I expected one characteristic to reveal a value of the weight being displayed on the scale and instead I got very large hex values, nothing at all, or some string value such as "OTA_DATA".

Comment: We don't know the model of the scale and we only have a screen capture of some of the characteristics in some scenario. We know even less than you do. What can we say? If it doesn't follow any standard then you'll just need to reverse engineer it. Capture the characteristics in different scenarios like 1) an empty scale 2) some weight on the scale 3) more weight on the scale etc.

Comment: Oh, shoot I must have deleted the model on mistake as I did have that once I started the thread, one second. The problem with capturing the characteristics is that its always the same every single time. It could be 30lbs it could be 150lbs it always shows the same values for every characteristic.

On top of that, I have come here to learn the steps of reverse engineering this device. I am very new to Bluetooth and BLE technology more specifically hence the reason I am here asking for guidance on the next steps.

Could it be that the data is encrypted and hence the reason it does not show?